# Introducing a new tag for geometric puzzles

Tags: discussion, tagging

While re-tagging [questions with homework as the only tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=[homework]%20is%3Aquestion), I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570913/tetromino-proof). It is about a geometric puzzle, filling a rectangle with integer side lengths using integer-side-shaped figures (more precisely, tetrominos). My aim was to add another tag besides [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), but this time I really couldn't think of an appropriate tag.

I'm sure such questions concerning geometric puzzles have shown up before on MSE, but to my knowledge no appropriate tag has yet been created.

So here is my question:

> Does such a tag already exist? If not, is this subject too localized to create a new tag? If not, what should the tag's name be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I retagged the question using [tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling), [discrete-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-geometry), and [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). I think we don't need a special tag for such things.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know [tag:tiling] and [tag:discrete-geometry].

Comment: @barto Pro tip: when unsure what tags to use, look at the tags used for questions in the Related column.

Comment: Yes, I had been doing that, but apparently didn't think of doing so when I saw that question.

Comment: @barto Slightly off-topic: I do appreciate your retagging help, but please consider also the titles. They don't have to be picture-perfect, but when the title is "How can I prove?", I'm sure you could fix that along with the tag. (I fixed this one already).

Comment: Usually I do change those things, but I may sometimes forget to. Thanks for the reminder. (Less than 100 questions left ;-)

Comment: @barto Looks like all homework-only questions were retagged, except for closed ones. I'm hoping the closed once can be deleted, saving the trouble of bumping them...

Comment: @barto There also exists a tag called ([tag:puzzle]). It was also discussed in [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-math-puzzle-on-topic-or-off-topic).